# Optimizing shapefile lookup time?

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, gadm

I have a ~1GB shapefile which is running circles around a ~5MB shapefile when it comes to feature look-up time (using Python, with GDAL):

```
def check(name, lat, lon, attributeFilter:'SQL Query'=None):
    shp = openShapefile(name)
    layer = shp.layer

    p = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    p.SetPoint_2D(0, lon, lat)

    layer.SetSpatialFilter(p)
    if attributeFilter:
        layer.SetAttributeFilter(attributeFilter)

    for feature in layer:
        return shp.getFields(feature)

    return None

>>> timeit("check('urban', 50.469815, 30.409954)", "from locationgenerator import check", number=1000)
20.37787419225606
>>> timeit("check('regions', 50.469815, 30.409954)", "from locationgenerator import check", number=1000)
0.26346330684964414
```

Basically the code is checking if the shape file contains any feature at the given coordinates.
`openShapefile` is a helper function that opens & caches the shapefile for the given name.

The 'regions' shapefile is http://www.gadm.org/version2.
The 'urban' shapefile is https://koordinates.com/layer/1285-world-urban-areas-110-million/.

As you can see, the larger and much higher resolution file performs around 100 times better, which is very suprising to me.

Things I have noticed:

- it's not the call to `getFields` (another helper function of mine), replacing it with return True exhibits the same behaviour
- if I modify the regions file (e.g. remove some features, merge some features, etc.), the performance drops several orders of magnitude - which leads me to believe this behaviour is due to some arcane pre-calculated optimizations performed on the shapefile.

How can I achieve at least comparable performance for the much simpler shapefile?

Comment: I suppose that the slow one is missing the .qix spatial index file. Or .sbx which is the native ESRI variant.

Comment: Nope, both have a shx file. However I suppose the faster one could have a better index - what tool would I use to generate a new index to see if it helps?

Comment: Sorry, I meant sbx (corrected now). Shptree is the tool.

Comment: Yep, creating a spatial index made the performance more like I was expecting - thanks a lot :). If you want, add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Building a spatial index speeds up the process. you can build a new index for the slower file using Shptree.